# Android Studio: How to implement a notification panel with several messages within an app

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on on a smart app project which uses automation of sensors. I have sent values from the sensors to cloud and I am able to retrieve the values on my mobile app which I have developed. I want to receive alerts/notifications on my app on my Alerts fragment as such: [image]

As shown in the picture, the notifications will notify the user when the value has exceeded a certain threshold, the current state of the sensor, the action to be performed based on the conditions, the time of the notification and the ability to dismiss the notification("Mark as Read").

All I want to know is how I can implement this tray-like notification within the app.

Comment: Forgive my retentiveness, but why would you implement this inside your app? This is what the system notification bar is for.

And suppose you do implement this - how would the user open it without opening the system notification bar?

If you're really set on doing this, I'd suggest going the way Facebook are doing with their "activity panel" (where you get notified when someone likes your posts).

Comment: To be able to view all the actions that are being performed by the sensors for a remote control of my smart greenhouse project.

Comment: Then I would steer away from mimicking the system notification trey. Either create a feed of your own (like the FB app does) or drop all of your notifications where they should be - in the system notification trey.

Comment: I wanted to know if there is any  layout for this in Android Studio or any widgets that can do that but apparently I would have to create my own feed. Thanks for your reply.. Will work with the Notifications provided by Android Studio rather